# MongoDB F# IgnoreExtraElements

Tags: mongodb, f#

I am using the MongoDB.Fsharp Driver and I've got some fields in newer records that I don't have in older records for a given collection.

So when I want to create a query that includes older records, it gives me the following exception: MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: No matching creator found.

I've googled around and apparently I need to add the below code but it still doesn't work. I've also tried to annotate the type with the BsonIgnoreExtraElements atrribute but that does not work either.

```
let pack = ConventionPack();
pack.Add(IgnoreExtraElementsConvetion(true))
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreExtraElements", pack, (fun -> _ -> true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is relevant but should

```
IgnoreExtraElementsConvetion
```

be

```
IgnoreExtraElementsConve**n**tion
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Also - and this is a total guess, should

```
(fun -> _ -> true)
```

be

```
(fun _ -> true)
```